# Switcheroo or ACPI call: Which is the better option and what are the differences?

Tags: video, ati, acpi, hybrid

I'm running Natty 64-bit on my Acer TimelineX 3820TG.This notebook has a switchable graphics card (ATI Radeon HD5650 and Intel Chipset).

Currently I am **not** using the `fglrx` drivers. I am a little confused as to how or which way to switch between the cards.

I have downloaded and compiled `ACPI_Call` and can load this with the following commands:

```
sudo insmod acpi_call.ko
test_off.sh
```

This works well for switching to the Intel Chipset and giving me about 7 hours of battery life (very sweet). However, that comes at a cost as I am not able to switch back to the ATI GPU (it causes my system to freeze and the only way to recover is `REISUB`), which is required if I want to put the laptop into sleep mode.

I recently read somewhere that `switcheroo` was actually made for the ATI/Intel cards so it raised a few questions for me which I hope someone can answer:

- what is the difference between `switcheroo` and `acpi_call`?
- What are the advantages/disadvantage of the two solutions?
- How exactly do I use `switcheroo` on Natty?
  -- if it's built into the kernel, shouldn't it be automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used both on my 4820TG.  Near as I can tell I go from 4.5 to 5 hours on battery with acpi_call to 4 hours with vga_switcheroo.  Wifi on, basic web browsing stuff.

With vga_switcheroo suspend works whether the ATI is on or off.  I do not use the ATI in linux at this time, just windows for gaming.  However if I hibernate with the ATI off, when the machine awakens the ATI is on and cannot now be shut down without a reboot.

acpi_call simply results in a hang when suspending or hibernating.

Comment: Assuming that switcheroo is just there on Natty you just do this: echo "OFF"  > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

Comment: thanks for the feedback. So ACPI_Call would provide better battry life whilst switcheroo allows me to suspend while the intel card is on (but resuming in ATI). I've tried turning on switcheroo but I get this: sudo "OFF" > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
bash: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Permission denied

Comment: The redirect works as you not root.  Try echo "OFF"|sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch